# GCP The user does not have access to service account '###-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'. But I have the permission granted in the console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

`Error: Error waiting for instance to create: The user does not have access to service account '###-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: 'tfccount@bxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account`

I have that exact role on the service account. Permissions under service account. That role to that user is assigned. What else is there I should do?

Comment: The error suggests that you don't have the correct role/permissions. If you can access `gcloud`, can you try `gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy ${PROJECT_NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --flatten=bindings --filter="bindings.role=\"roles/iam.serviceAccountUser\"" --format="value(bindings.members)"`? Does the result include the Service Account `tfccount@bxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`?